# Figuring out Silverlight namespaces and assemblies

Tags: silverlight, namespaces

Often when you find examples of Silverlight code on the web it may only contain a snippet of code rather than the full set needed to make it work. This causes me immense frustration when I am trying to work out what namespace and/or assembly declaration to use at the top of the xaml file.

For example, take the following snippet (which shows how to add a list of items as a static resource)

```
<UserControl.Resources>   
   <controls:ObjectCollection x:Key="SampleData">  
      <sys:String>User 1</sys:String>  
      <sys:String>User 2</sys:String>  
      <sys:String>User 3</sys:String>  
   </controls:ObjectCollection>  
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How is it possible for me to determine what namespace and assembly this guy used as the "controls" alias???

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is:

- Try to add the element to my Xaml, Resharper will help me here if the class is within a referenced assembly.
- Search the documentation for the class name. Silverlight sdk doc and then the Toolkit doc.

In this case, in SL3, the ObjectCollection class is within the Toolkit:

Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls

Assembly:  System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit (in System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll)

Comment: Good tips. Without R#, I would say use Reflector, load in all the Silverlight reference and SDK assemblies, and others like the Toolkit. Then you can Search on the member names and types.